# Why PointsMaterial in three.js is not working on my geometry?

Tags: three.js

I have used PointsMaterial to create particles in three.js in console it is working fine but nothing appearing on the screen,my screen is black and the position of my camera is

// Base camera

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)

camera.position.z = 3

scene.add(camera)

and i didn't forget to add it to the scene

[this is the picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAqnh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your point size is 0.02, but to show particle big as one pixel you should use default size 1.0 .